# can i use sql server 2008 management studio on a sql server 2005 db?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Can i use the sql server 2008 r2 management studio to connect to a sql server 2005 db?

Are there are no side effects like upgrading or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Intellisense doesn't work against SQL Server 2005 instances but no other issues that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The Management Studio is nothing than a UI frontend to the SQL Server instances shipping from Microsoft. It won't change any settings regarding your database configurations. Newer SSMS versions are backwards compatible with older SQL Server releases.

You could use any other 3rd party SQL Server management software for managing your SQL Server instances if you want.